# JPA cascade on entities from multiple persistenceUnits

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1

I have an unidirectional relation between two entities:

```
*@Entity
public class XXX{
  @Id
  private Long Id;
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "YYY_ID")
  private YYY yyy;
}
@Entity
public class YYY{
   @Id
   private Long Id;

   private String someName;
}*
```

The entities belong to different schemas in the same database (but i may not use synonims, or give grants to schema...), so i have two persistence units:

1.persistenceUnit(xxx) - entity xxx is mapped there

2.persistenceUnit(yyy) - entity yyy is mapped there

Can i make jpa to auto perform cascade on the other persistence unit?
Example:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "xxx")
private EntityManager em;

XXX xxx = new XXX();
YYY yyy = new YYY();
yyy.setSomeName("just some name"):
xxx.setYYY(yyy);
em.persist(xxx);
```

This should create two objects...

Is it possible? Help appreciated. Im using JPA2, Hibernate 4 on Jboss7

Answer (score 1):

The JPA specification does not mandate that mappings across multiple persistent units be supported.

You can however, depending on your database permissions, use one persistence unit and use the @Table annotation to specify the scheme/catalog for any Entities not in the default schema.

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="xyz")
public class XXX{
  @Id
  private Long Id;
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "YYY_ID")
  private YYY yyy;
}
```

Otherwise you would need to look for a solution at the database level or consider using a provider specific solution: I am not aware of anything for Hibernate but see, for example, the following EclipseLink functionality:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Composite

> Starting with EclipseLink 2.3.0 JPA developers can now combine
>   persistence units together at runtime allowing entities to be stored
>   in different databases. **This includes support for relationships
>   between entities in different persistence units** (references across
>   databases)

Comment: no i can't, as i said before: The entities belong to different schemas in the same database (but i may not use synonims, or give grants to schema...). So one schema doesn't see the other.